# Visual Studio Code all extensions are gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I opened VS Code today, and found that all of my extensions were gone. I had signed in with GitHub with settings sync. I don't know how this happened.

Usually, I have extensions like Tabnine, Atom Material Theme, GitLens, GitHub Copilot, etc., but today, all of them were somehow gone.

I use Debian (`Linux x64 5.10.0-9-amd64`).

**EDIT:**
Turns out that I had to go to the `command palette`->`Settings Sync: Show Synced Data` and choose an older backup. It restored most of the extensions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like your synchronized profile had no extensions installed.  You should reinstall the extensions

Comment: Just the day before, I had all of the extensions on the github account

Comment: Had the same on Mac just now, seems like a bug on VSCode

Comment: Please post the answer as answer, not in the question.